# R, rename thousands of downloaded files

Tags: r, loops, download, file-rename

I have a question which drives me crazy. I have the following tables as my source table:

`v1    v2`

`1   http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/20/0000893220-01-000315.txt`

`2   http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/20/0000893220-03-000441.txt`

`3   http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/20/0000893220-04-000596.txt`

`4   http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/20/0000893220-05-000728.txt`

`5   http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/20/0000893220-06-000650.txt`

`.....`

Basically, I have the ID in `V1` and URL in `V2`. I need  to download thousands of similar file at once. So far I  solved the problem of downloading by using following code:(lets say `link` is the dataset containing the table I provide above)

`urls<-c(link$v2)`

`for (url in urls){
  download.file(url, destfile = basename(url), quiet=T)
}`

This code works fine for downloading. However, now, instead of keeping the name of the downloaded file as original basename such as `0000893220-01-000315.txt` or `0000893220-03-000441.txt` etc, I wish to change the file name according to the ID in v1, to name the file as `1.txt`,  `2.txt` etc.

Can anyone help me to solve this? Very appreciated to your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file.rename` :

```
with(link, file.rename(basename(v2), paste0(v1, ".txt")))
```

Alternately, give them the name you want when you download them:

```
nr <- nrow(link)
for(i in 1:nr) with(link[i,], download.file(v2, destfile = paste0(v1, ".txt"), quiet=TRUE))
```